# How to use react native fetch() to retrieve malformed json from api

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to retrieve the api result as plain text and I will parse the malformed json, however the response.text() is not working in this case:

```
client.fetch("POST", path, headers, data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.text());});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.text()` returns a `Promise`, you should handle that Promise with another `then`, like that:

```
client.fetch("POST", path, headers, data)
  .then(response => 
       response.text().then(text => console.log(text) );
   );
```

By the way, if the response is a JSON object you can use `response.json()` instead od `response.text()`.